# File after leaving an activity where it was saved, does not refresh in other activities

Tags: android, file, save, refresh, reload

I have a specific problem. I have an application with many activities. In activity "settings.class" I create "config.txt" file and I save it - everything is OK. When I try to read from this file in the same activity, I get a string which I saved into this file. BUT when I close this activity "settings.class" and I return back to the "MainActivity.class" and I try to read from this "config.txt" file I get an old string which was stored before NOT actually saved...

I solved my problem with restart my application and after that everything is OK. But I want to know why this happens.

Here is my code:

This is in class utilities:

```
  public void WriteSettingFile(String txt_msg, Context ctx) throws IOException
{
    FileOutputStream fp = null;

    fp = ctx.openFileOutput("edog_con.txt",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);   
    fp.write(txt_msg.getBytes());   
    fp.close();     
}

    private String ReadSettingFile(Context ctx) throws IOException
{
    FileInputStream fp;
    String tmp_string;
    StringBuilder sb = null;


    fp = ctx.openFileInput("edog_con.txt");
    if (fp != null)
    {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fp);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        sb = new StringBuilder();

        while( (tmp_string = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(tmp_string);
        }

        fp.close();         
    }


    return sb.toString();
}

// Vrati ulozene telefonne cislo
public String GetPhoneNumber (Context ctx)
{
    String tmp = "";
    String[] casti;

    // Nacitanie suboru. Ak nie je, tak vrat chybu
    try 
    {
        tmp = ReadSettingFile(ctx);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        return "err";
    }

    // Ak retazec obsahuje ',' - mal by - tak pokracuj. Ak nie chyba
    if (tmp.contains(","))
    {
        // rozdel string na dve casti - pred a po ciarke. pred je tel. cislo
        casti = tmp.split(",");
    }
    else
        return "err";

    return casti[0];
}
```

This is in the Setting.class where I am writing to the .txt file. When I try to read from file in this activity class, everything is OK and I have an actual data saved into .txt file

```
public class Settings extends Activity
{
  ....

  // Save button and so on

  ... 
Utilities ut = new Utilities();
try
{
     ut.WriteSettingFile(save_info, Settings.this);
} 
catch (IOException e)
{   
    alert_msg.setMessage(R.string.alert_bad_file).show();
}

// I have to reset the application instead of this - and then it works
Settings.this.finish();

 .... 
}
```

And when I try to read from file in this fragment Water.class , I read previous saved string not actually saved. I have to reset application so previous "Settings.this.finish()"
I dont use, and I reset a whole application programatically.

Water.class

```
 public class Water extends Fragment
 {
...
Utilities ut = new Utilities();
String data;

...

    // This gets an old saved string in .txt file
data = ut.GetPhoneNumber(this.getActivity())

  }
```

Comment: Why not `use SharedPreferences`?  This is exactly what it's designed for.

Comment: Yes, but I want to generate some reports for another applications (and I want to save a long text messages), so I think that .txt file is better then SharedPreferences for me

Comment: OK, are you using `flush()`?  Actually, we can guess for a long time.  Please post **relevant** code where you close and re-open the file.

Comment: OK, thank you! I've just edited my post. Please, look at it

Comment: I tried it with flush() and nothing - its still the same problem.